# How to add new row to a databound gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to add a new blank row to my gridview whenever the user clicks the Add row button. Ideally, whichever row they click this button, a new row would be inserted just below that row. 
I've read through a lot of the previous questions but I still cannot get my gridview to display a new blank row.

Page code:

```
<table>
    ...
    ...
<td colspan="3" align="left" style="border: thin solid #000000; vertical-align: top; background-color: #4B6C9E">
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
     <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdHours" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" 
   ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" VerticalAlign="Top" Height="20px"/>
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="Task">
                                <ItemTemplate>                                                
                                    <asp:Label ID="BufferLabel" runat="server" Text="" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TaskList" runat="server" CssClass="myDropDownSearch" Width="80%"
                                        onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" value="Select a Task..."></asp:TextBox>    
                                    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchEmployees" 
                                        MinimumPrefixLength="3"
                                        CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10"
                                        TargetControlID="TaskList" 
                                        ID="AutoCompleteExtender3" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
                                    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                </ItemTemplate> 
                                <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Weekday" HeaderText="Weekday" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="4%" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Date" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="8%" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hours">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblHours" Visible='<%# NOT IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Hours") %>' CssClass="hoursLabel" />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Hours") %>' 
                                        Width="90%" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>'>
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Minutes">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMins" Visible='<%# NOT IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Minutes") %>' CssClass="hoursLabel" />
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="myDropDown" selectedValue='<%# Eval("Minutes") %>'  Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' >
                                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activity" >
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblActivity" Visible='<%# NOT IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Activity") %>' CssClass="hoursLabel" />
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" width="75%" selectedValue='<%# Eval("Activity") %>' Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>'>
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select Activity</asp:ListItem>  
                                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Prescope</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Scope</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Design/Build Configuration</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Testing</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Training</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Implementation/Validation</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Maintenance & Ongoing Support</asp:ListItem>                    
                                        <asp:ListItem>Project Management</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Shared Time</asp:ListItem>                
                                   </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" visible="false" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle Width="20%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="AddEntries">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnHoursRow" runat="server" Text="+" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' OnClick="btnNewEntryRow_Click" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="5%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="AddNotes">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNotes" Visible='<%# NOT IsInEditMode %>' runat="server"  CssClass="hoursLabel" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddNotes" runat="server" Text="Add Notes" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' />
                                    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnAddNotes_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
                                        DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="pnlNotes" 
                                        TargetControlID="btnAddNotes" 
                                        OkControlID="btnNotesDone">
                                    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="5%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False"  HeaderText="Validator">
                                <ItemTemplate>            
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Whole Numbers Only" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="HoursasIntegers"
                                            ValidationExpression="\d+" SetFocusOnError="False" Width="75%" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>                                 
                                </ItemTemplate> 
                                <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="ErrMessage">
                                <ItemTemplate>                                                
                                    <asp:Label ID="ActivityErrorMessage" runat="server" Text="You must select an Activity for entered hours." Visible="False" ForeColor="#FF0000" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate> 
                                <ItemStyle Width="19%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="TimeNotes">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlNotes" runat="server" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' Width="75%" BackColor="#4B6C9E" Height="300px">
                                        <table width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Notes Below:" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" CssClass="myTextbox"
                                                        TextMode="MultiLine"  Text='<%# Eval("TimeNotes") %>' Height="200"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnNotesDone" runat="server" Text="Done" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnNotesCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnNotesCancel_Click"  Visible="False" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="4%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" Height="20px" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                 </td>
```

Code behind:

```
    Protected Sub btnNewEntryRow_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

            '    Dim clickedRow = TryCast(DirectCast(sender, Button).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
            '    Dim clickedIndex = clickedRow.RowIndex

        'Just hard coded a value for now
            BindGrdHours(3)

    End Sub

  Private Sub BindGrdHours(ByVal rowIndex As Integer)

        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

        If ViewState("CurrentGridTable") IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim dtCurrentTable As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentGridTable"), DataTable)
            Dim drCurrentRow As DataRow = Nothing

            If dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 1 To dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count

                    Dim TaskList As TextBox = DirectCast(grdHours.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("TaskList"), TextBox)
                    'Dim TextBoxAge As BoundField
                    'TextBoxAge.DataField = grdHours.Rows(rowcount).Cells(2).FindControl("Weekday").ToString
                    'Dim TextBoxAddress As BoundField
                    'TextBoxAddress.DataField = grdHours.Rows(rowcount).Cells(3).FindControl("Date").ToString
                    Dim Hours As TextBox = DirectCast(grdHours.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(4).FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
                    Dim Minutes As DropDownList = DirectCast(grdHours.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(5).FindControl("DropDownList2"), DropDownList)
                    Dim Activity As DropDownList = DirectCast(grdHours.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(6).FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList)
                    Dim AddEntries As Button = DirectCast(grdHours.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(7).FindControl("btnHoursRow"), Button)
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow()
                    ' drCurrentRow("RowNumber") = i + 1

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Task") = TaskList.Text.ToString
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Weekday") = grdHours.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(2).Text.ToString
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Date") = grdHours.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(3).Text.ToString
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Hours") = Hours.Text.ToString
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Minutes") = Minutes.SelectedValue.ToString
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Activity") = Activity.SelectedValue.ToString
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("AddEntries") = AddEntries.Text.ToString
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("AddNotes") = String.Empty
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Validator") = String.Empty
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("ErrMessage") = String.Empty
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("TimeNotes") = String.Empty
                    rowIndex += 1
                Next

                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow)
                ViewState("CurrentGridTable") = dtCurrentTable

                grdHours.DataSource = dtCurrentTable
                grdHours.DataBind()

                Dim txn As TextBox = DirectCast(grdHours.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
                ' txn.Focus;
                txn.Focus()

            End If

        End If

        enterHours(True)

    End Sub
```

When I click the button, the btnNewEntryRow_Click function is being called, which in turns calls BindGrdHours() successfully but after completion, nothing is happening. The screen still contains the original gridview.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? Thanks for looking.

Comment: The grid is only "face" of your data. Think about that you should add row not to the grid but to the `datasourse` and grid should reflect the new state of your data. Now. I believe this logic is flawed. Why add empty row to the grid or source? Input data into controls and then click `add`. Don't add an empty row.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am beginning to think in the way you mention by adding information to the backend. Just to give more substance to what I am trying to do: I have a gridview that is, initially, displaying a row for the 7 days of the selected week. This allows the user to enter an activity per day. There are times when the user wishes to enter another record for a particular day to indicate multiple activities for that day.

Comment: Please, don't reinvent the bicycle. What you have is Master-Detail. Master is your grid, detail - should be a set of controls displaying information for the selected row. Your grid may display 10 fields of data but your detail may have 20. If you add new row - click New, enter data into some text boxes and click Save. All software works like this. Even the form in which I typed this comment - I clicked "Add Comment", I typed this comment, And now I will click the button to Save this comment